# Pac4j - CORS Allow Origin Not Matching Origin

Tags: keycloak, pac4j, javalin

My javalin API receive a request on a route secured by pac4j.
But no matter what I try, I always end up with a "CORS Allow Origin Not Matching Origin" error on OPTION, and "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI" on GET
Unprotected route works normally.

Here is my api :

```
val securityHandler: SecurityHandler = SecurityHandler(authenticationConfig, "KeycloakOidcClient")
app.before("/protected", securityHandler)
app.get("/protected") { ctx ->
  ctx.result("Hello Keycloak protected!")
}
app.get("/notprotected") { ctx ->
  ctx.result("Hello unprotected!")
}
```

And here is my config :

```
fun setUpAuthentication(properties: Properties): AuthenticationConfig {

  val oidcConfig: KeycloakOidcConfiguration = KeycloakOidcConfiguration()
  oidcConfig.setClientId(properties.get(KEYCLOAK_ID))
  oidcConfig.setSecret(properties.get(KEYCLOAK_SECRET))
  oidcConfig.setDiscoveryURI(properties.get(KEYCLOAK_DISC_URI))
  oidcConfig.setBaseUri(properties.get(KEYCLOAK_BASE_URI))
  oidcConfig.setRealm(properties.get(KEYCLOAK_REALM))
  oidcConfig.setClientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)

  val keyCloakClient = KeycloakOidcClient(oidcConfig)
  val clients = Clients(properties.get(API_BASE_URL)+"/callback", keyCloakClient)
  val config = AuthenticationConfig(clients)
  config.addAuthorizer("csfr", CsrfAuthorizer())
  return config
}
```

My keycloak client is configured with both the front-end and back-end url as allowed web origins (I even tried * or /* but it doesn't change anything)

What could be the cause ?

Edit :

I just tried to add a CorsMatcher as suggested but to no effect :

```
val corsMatcher = CorsMatcher()
corsMatcher.setAllowOrigin(null)
config.addMatcher("cors", corsMatcher)
return config
```

@jleleu is it what you had in mind in order to "a CORS configuration with the null host" ?

Edit 2 :

```
val keyCloakClient = KeycloakOidcClient(oidcConfig)
val clients = Clients(properties.get(API_BASE_URL)+"/callback", keyCloakClient)
val config = AuthenticationConfig(clients)
val corsMatcher = CorsMatcher()
corsMatcher.setAllowOrigin(properties.get(FRONT_URL) + " " + properties.get(KEYCLOAK_BASE_URI))
// also tried 
// corsMatcher.setAllowOrigin(properties.get(FRONT_URL))
// corsMatcher.setAllowOrigin(properties.get(KEYCLOAK_BASE_URI))
// but reading Matcher code it seems to overwrite the first one 
config.addMatcher("cors", corsMatcher)
return config
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, security headers are applied by pac4j. Can you try using the `SecurityHandler(authenticationConfig, "KeycloakOidcClient", "isAuthenticated", "none")` constructor?

Comment: thank you for your response ! I tried but still get the same error message, would you have another suggestion ?

Comment: I remember some issue with Keycloak where I was forced to apply a CORS configuration with the `null` host via the `CorsMatcher`

Comment: Thanks again, I edited my question to include the matcher configuration I tried after your suggestion. It didn't work by I'm not at all sure of the way it needs to be configured.

Comment: Yes, the configuration is what I had in mind. Though, you also need to add it in the  `SecurityHandler`: `SecurityHandler(authenticationConfig, "KeycloakOidcClient", "isAuthenticated", "cors")`

Comment: Oh ! That changed things ! Thank you ! I now have a new error "CORS preflight did not suceed", would you know its cause ?

Comment: The CORS configuration is now properly taken into account but it seems that an OPTION request fails: can you check your network logs in your browser and see the "Origin" header of this OPTION request?

Comment: the origin is the frontend url : localhost:5173. It's included as allowed origin in keycloak but does is need to be added somewhere in the pac4j configuration ? I tried to use it instead of null in setAllowedOrigin but to no avail

Comment: The CORS configuration in pac4j protects a request from Keycloak to pac4j. For an automatic form post after a sucessful login a Keycloak, I think there is a preflight request (OPTIONS), this is the request on which you should look for the "Origin" header and set it properly on your pac4j configuration.

Comment: oh indeed, I expect keycloak will call on the /callback route and must be allowed. I added the url to allowed path but still get the "Cors preflight did not succeed". I added my tentative in the question. Thank you for your help and sorry for the delay this is a side project on my free time and I can't work on it as often as I would like.